# Shifting after dynamically adding a point creates a space in chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

So I'm using Highcharts to plot data from real time every 1 second. After 40 points being added to the chart I start shifting the points. The problem is that I have more than one series in the chart and when it start to shift it creates a weird space in from of all series except the first one..

[image: chart]

As you can see on the red doesnt start in the same place of the blue one.

```
    setLiveDataPoint: function(data){
        var graph = this;
        var num = graph.yAxis.length; // Number of Y axis (Field, Quality)
        var yAxis = graph.yAxis;

        for(var i = 0; i < num; i++){
            var xFieldId = "time"; // defaults to time
            var serie = graph.highchartObj.get(yAxis[i].id);
            var x = parseInt(data[xFieldId][data.records - 1]);
            var y = data[yAxis[i].id][data.records - 1];
            var shift;
            if(graph.pointsOnGraph == 40){
                shift = true;
            } else {
                shift = false;
                if(i == 0){
                    graph.pointsOnGraph += 1;
                }
            }
            serie.addPoint({
                x: x,
                y: y
            }, true, shift);
        }

        return graph;
```

When I make a call have every data in the same json response, then I loop for the yAxis to plot the point in the chart..

Comment: please provide your code. best would be to make a jsfiddle.

Comment: Please replicate this issue as live demo, on the jsfiddle.net